# Parsing a file in C with several similar blocks

Tags: c, file, parsing

I have a file that has the following format:

```
abc dca
2
aa bb
casca casss

abc dca
3
aa bb
casca casss
casca casss

abcd abcd
0
```

Basically it goes by blocks (in the previous example there would be 3 blocks). A particular block would be:

```
abc dca
2
aa bb
casca casss
```

In all case we would have: 
First line: Always two words separated by a space. 
Second line: A number

From here, we would have as many lines as the previous number, and each line would have always two words.

How can I parse a file so that for each block I can call a function passing some stuff that I calculate with what I have found in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a minimal state machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int qrgc, char **argv)
{
char buff[111];
char one[10], two[10];
char left[10], right[10];
int num;
size_t len;
int state,rc;

state =0;

while(fgets (buff, sizeof buff, stdin)) {
        len = strlen (buff);
        while (len && buff[len-1] == '\n') buff[--len] = 0;
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
                rc = sscanf(buff, "%s %s", left, right);
                if (rc < 2) goto quit;
                state=1;
                break;
        case 1:
                rc = sscanf(buff, "%d", &num);
                if (rc < 1) goto quit;
                state=2;
                break;
        default:
                if (!len) {state = 0; continue; }
                rc = sscanf(buff, "%s %s", one, two);
                if (rc < 2) goto quit;
                break;
                }
        }
quit: ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: wildplasser this is a really nice approach. However, I have a doubt. For each block, I need to call a function and pass the parameters that I have found (first line words and the words that come after the integer). By doing a state machine I don't really know in which block am I right? how could I solve this? I mean, let's say that for the first block I would call a function like this doLogic(abc,dca,mapping_rules); Where mapping_rules is an array of structs that hold origin and destiny. Origin would be aa and destiny bb for the first line, and casca and casss for the second.

Comment: Yes, this is just a skeleton. You'll need to add the actual payload: allocating nodes, reallocating arrays, etc. That *could* be done in subfunctions, but if it is small, it could be added to the case blocks, too.

Comment: I know it's a skeleton :) I just fail to see at which point I would call my function. How do I now that I have finished a block?

Comment: Try to understand the state machine. It finished a block when it switches back from state=2-->>state=0. If it were a function, you could return a single record (:= 2+N lines) from there, a subsequent call would start at state=0, and return the next record, if any.

Comment: wildplasser, if at the state of the case 1 I want to initialize an array of the size of num, and I want to use that array in the default case, how can I do that? Or in other words, how do I pass variables between states?

Comment: The state machine is overkill here, state 0 is followed by state 1, which leads to a loop reading the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The two I thought of are:

If the file is not very large, then you could read it all into a list of strings (one string for each line).

Another way is to pass create a function that takes a file handle and the previous block.

(I do not want to write dynamic arrays in C)