# Reading a file in C - Problems with scope and context

Tags: c, parsing, file-io, scope

I have to parse a file that has several entries separated by a blank line.  Each entry has the following format:

```
ab bababa
2
ab bba
b ba
```

Where:

1. First line: Will have two words separated by a white space.
2. Second line: Will have an integer that will indicate how many more lines need to be taken into account
3. Next lines: Will have each one two words, separated by a white space.

At the end of each entry, I need to call a function and pass some parameters found in the entry.  Specifically, I need to pass the first two words found in the first line and an array that will contain structs representing the lines that come after the integer. The struct definition looks like this:

```
typedef struct t_transformation_rule {
    char *needle;
    char *replacement;
} transformation_rule;
```

As I have stated, a file can have several entries. So a specific file could look like this:

```
ab bababa
2
ab bba
b ba

a abba
3
a bb
bb abba
a abba

abcd abcd
0

abab bbbaaa
2
ab aaa
ab bbb
```

Here is what I have done in order to parse it, but I am having troubles because when I find the number, I initialize an array of structs, and then afterwards I try to use that array and store the next lines, but that variable is out of the scope.  Here is the code:

```
void processFile(char *file_name)
{
    char buff[120];
    char needle[20], replacement[20];
    char origin[20], target[20];

    int num, rule_counter;
    size_t len;

    int context,rc;
    transformation_rule *rules_list;

    context =0;
    rule_counter = 0;

    FILE *in = fopen(file_name,"r");

    if (in != NULL) {
      while(fgets (buff, sizeof buff, in)) {
        len = strlen (buff);
        while (len && buff[len-1] == '\n') {
          buff[--len] = 0;
        }
        if (context == 0) {
          rc = sscanf(buff, "%s %s", origin, target);
          context = 1;
        }
        if (context == 1) {
          rc = sscanf(buff, "%d", &num);
          transformation_rule rules_list[num];
          context = 2;
        }
        if (context == 2) {
          if (!len) {
              context = 0;
              continue;
          }
          rc = sscanf(buff, "%s %s", needle, replacement);
          transformation_rule *rule = malloc(sizeof(transformation_rule));

          rule->needle = needle;
          rule->replacement = replacement;

          // HERE I GET THE ERROR SAYING THAT RULES_LIST IS NOT DEFINED
          rules_list[rule_counter] = rule;
          rule_counter++;
        }

      }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if you guys could tell me what am I doing wrong, or how could I do this easier.

Comment: Learn to enable warnings and debugging info when compiling (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux). Read more about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing and represent each entire entry in memory. BTW, your program did not define `rules_list` (maybe it should be some `calloc`-ed pointer?).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the line where I declare rules_list.  It's in the condition of context == 1

Comment: Your `rule_list` is a pointer to pointers, declare it as `transformation_rule **rules_list = NULL;`

Comment: Your knowledge of basic C programming is too weak. Take time to read a good C programming book. It looks like you don't understand what you are coding. And please use a debugger (and ask for all warnings by your compiler).

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch. Ok. I was just trying to understand how could I parse this file. Thanks though.

Comment: Also, Basile, if I declare rules_list as a pointer to pointers, I can't treat it as an array right? That's what I wanted originally..

Comment: Ah, I see you replaced my beautiful switch by a kludge of chained ifs. Without the break and continues. And you are also ignoring the return value from sscanf().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15043927/905902 Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done simpler: You were reading parts with `fscanf` and then parsing them with `sscanf`. That is *fine* but in **this case** this might be what you are looking for:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
void process(char* start, char* target, int cRules, char** froms, char** tos) {
    // work with it
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc!=2) { 
        printf("need filename\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(!f) {
        printf("wrong filename\n");
        return 2;
    }
    char* start = malloc(1000);
    char* target = malloc(1000);
    int cRules;
    while(fscanf(f, "%s %s %i", start, target, &cRules)!=EOF) {
        printf("\ntask %s->%s\nnumber of rules %i\n", start, target, cRules);
        char** froms = malloc(cRules*sizeof(char*));
        char** tos = malloc(cRules*sizeof(char*));
        int iRule = 0; for(; iRule<cRules; ++iRule) {
            froms[iRule] = malloc(100);
            tos[iRule] = malloc(100);
            if(fscanf(f, "%s %s", froms[iRule], tos[iRule])==EOF) {
                printf("format error\n");
                fclose(f);
                return 3;
            };
            printf("rule %i %s->%s\n", iRule, froms[iRule], tos[iRule]);
        }
        process(start, target, cRules, froms, tos);
        for(iRule = 0; iRule<cRules; ++iRule) {
            free(froms[iRule]);
            free(tos[iRule]);
        }
        free(froms);
        free(tos);
    }
    free(start);
    free(target);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Eznme just one question, when you free(froms[iRule]) why do you do it? I am trying to access the froms[0] from inside the process and I get an undefined value.

Comment: oh sorry, it is a mistake, i will change it.